# Geo Node: Distributing Points on Selected Faces Above Average Z

Tags: geometry-nodes, faces, mathematics

I'm learning about geo nodes and came across a situation. I would like to distribute points on the faces of an object that are only above a certain Z value, calculated from the average z of all the faces of the same object. I could, of course, select the faces and separate them from the object in edit mode or use weight paint, but I had this theoretical question while using geo nodes. Thank u guys!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Attribute Statistic node can be used for this.

Basically separate the Z component from the position and feed it into the Attribute Statistic node. Now simply use the mean (mean and average are the same thing) output from the node and compare it with the Z component using Compare: Greater Than. Use the boolean output from the compare node as the selection for the Distribute Points on Faces node.

[image]

Comment: Thank you!
I had considered this logic, using the node attribute statistic and grather than, but had not been able to "link" the separate XYZ, thank you very much!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: @Thomas If your question has been answered satisfactorily, please consider marking it as "Accepted Answer" so that the question appears as solved. Thank you!